# jOOQ: Error parsing Oracle TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

I am having an issue parsing Oracle (11.2.0.4.0) `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE` values to `OffsetDateTime`:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014-03-28T15:11:49.508918 -4:00' could not be parsed at index 26
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.offsetDateTime(DefaultBinding.java:1539)
```

I think this is the issue described here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4965

The not-quite-iso8601 value produced by Oracle (`2014-03-28T15:11:49.508918 -4:00`) actually has two problems that are rejected by `OffsetDateTime.parse`:

- single-digit hour (as per #4965)
- space before the offset

Is there a workaround, until the fix arrives (in 3.9)?

Answer (score 2):

jOOQ version 3.8 does not yet fully support `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types (which would map to Java 8's JSR 310 types). For the time being, you will have to implement your own support via a data type binding as explained here in the manual:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings